# Anyone had luck installing nvidia drivers on ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: nvidia, 14.10

I have tried for two days to get my GF 750Ti Nvidia card to work in Ubuntu 14.10 without success - it only accepts 1024x768 (4:3) resolution and each time I use some of the guides on the net it either crashes or just goes black.

It works perfect without any extra steps in 13.10 so I am currently considering to use that version of Ubuntu instead.

Just wanted to know if its a general problem with 14.10 that it no longer supports nvidia cards?

Answer (score 0):

I installed Nvidia driver in Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 It installed without problems but i experience some kind of bugg. My background became pixelated and some webpages are pixelated such as chrome.google.com and some pictures too.

I installed the latest driver which i downloaded from Nvidia website and i also installed it from additional drivers to see if it worked but i experienced the same bugg.
Also when i Minimize and Maximize a window, the window goes black.

I have Nvidia GeForce GT755M SLI

Comment: Ok seems the best option is to go back to 13.10, shame nvidia is no longer supported

Comment: Yeah but 13.10 wont be supported anymore.
I hope there is some kind of fix for this bugg.